# Get last item from for loop after error occurs

Tags: python-3.x

I have a process that calls a lot of data in a for loop that's structured like this:

- Get all characters (~ 2000)
- For each character get all activities (~ 15 activities per character)

I using python to download all of this data, and it's a process that's constantly running. My question is this: is there a way for my python script to 'remember' the last character object it called in the event of an error? I have my script running on a loop, and it restarts itself if it has an error, but it restarts from the beginning of the loop instead of the last character that it called.

Here's some pseudo code to illustrate what I'm doing:

```
async def update_characters(parent):
get_characters = "{api-url}"
res = _get_characters_response(get_characters)
for character in res:  # if error remember this character object
    member_id = character['membershipId']
    character_id = character['characterId']
    activity_history = await _get_api_response(parent.api.get_activity_history, 4, member_id, character_id, 15,
                                                  0, 0)
    if len(activity_history['Response']) == 0:
        print("No activity history for " + str(character['characterName']
              + " (" + str(character_id) + ")"))
        continue
    else:
        for act in activity_history['Response']['activities']:
            activity_url = "{insert_activity_url}"
```

Comment: Your question is very broad, in the sense that you give very little detail...  If you want to always finish your loop, you could use `try:` `except ...:` control structures, but w/o some other detail mine is just a wild guess

Comment: Perhaps it was too broad a question. So I should rephrase it to asking about the object within the initial loop. Can python remember the object it was on in the event of an error using .pop(0)? So if the script gets an exception, and would normally break, can I restart the loop on the object it was last on?

Comment: I may be wrong, but if you receive an error on `pop(0)` it's because you have processed all the elements in the initial list and you do not need to restart the loop. If you do not want to show code, or pseudocode maybe, you won't get an answer.

Comment: I added some code for ya